# Unicode error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am trying to set a folder path as follows:

```
folderpath = "C:\\Users\NY1\\Dropbox\\Research ideas\\Final Code\\Poject_name"
```

and I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 9-10: malformed \N character escape

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that *really* the string that generates the error? You need to copy/paste or you're unlikely to get any help.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thank you; I updated the question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry; it was a dumb question

Comment: For paths, you should use or normal slashes (on Windows), or you can use `r"r:\aw\string\prefix"` that suppresses interpretation of characters as escape sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not escaping one of the backslashes (before `NY1`):

```
folderpath = "C:\\Users\NY1\\Dropbox\\Research ideas\\Final Code\\Poject_name"
```

...should be:

```
folderpath = "C:\\Users\\NY1\\Dropbox\\Research ideas\\Final Code\\Poject_name"
```

Notice that the exception is telling you the location of where this character occurs (position 9-10).

Comment: I need a nap! Thank you. Sorry for dumb question

Comment: @NNsr: We all need naps sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used ("C:\Users\JOHN-PC\Videos\ml-twitter-sentiment-analysis-develop\data\twittertrain.csv"). to remove this problem. you have \ before users and c.s.v file name .